# build failed when trying to run flutter app on a emulator (vscode)

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

I've tried to run a flutter application on an installed android emulator on vscode and the build error occurred

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2mgF.png)

Comment: Do you have net connection?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the error one of your package require a higher Android SDK version.

Go to the file
`android/app/build.gradle`

Search for
`compileSdkVersion`

And change its value to
`compileSdkVersion 33`

This might solve the problem